# How to extract text from an image with a variety of noisy texts and numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract, text-extraction, amazon-textract

I have an image here:

[image: metre]

I need to extract the meter readings from this image which is "0005053" at the centre.

I have tried pytesseract as follows:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("Screen_Shot_2564-08-25_at_11.23.13.png"))
print(text)
```

The output I got was `' \n\x0c'`.

Another service I found was [AWS Textract](https://console.aws.amazon.com/textract/home?region=us-east-1#/demo) which is extremely accurate but I couldn't find a workaround to implement that in python. Any leads there will be appreciated.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you always have the same framing of the subject matter? I don't think you can feed that image into anything that helps unless you extract a smaller region of the image.

Comment: Yes, the framing is always the same, the zoom levels might differ but not in great proportions.

Comment: How does pytesseract work when you crop the image down to just the numbers and run it through?

Comment: I cant take that route, because in the real time, the user is is going to the image just like the tagged one.

Comment: Yes but I am trying to determine if the issue is the OCR, or the noise in the image. You may need to find a process where you can help identify the region to OCR with some other detection algorithm and then pass the subregion to the OCR engine. It is a lot to just ask the OCR to find the text, given how many characters are all over the shot in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the textract route you can easily implement it using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.185/reference/services/textract.html#Textract.Client.detect_document_text).
You can also try using [AWS Rekognition](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.detect_text) to do the same task and see whether it is more accurate/cheaper